# Prove that $6$ and $2(1+\sqrt{-5})$ do not have a gcd in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that  $6$  and $2(1+\sqrt{-5})$ do not have a gcd. here those elements belong to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

They have common divisors like the number $2$ But if $a$ is another divisor it must divide the hypothetical gcd. What can i do?

Comment: Please pick titles that are not so generic. "Ring theory problem" could apply to thousands of problems, and is completely useless for anyone trying to search for your problem. I've already changed the title to something more useful. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD (Unique Factorization Domain), both $2,3,1+\sqrt{-5},1-\sqrt{-5}$ are irreducible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer  6 has as divisors $2,3, 1+\sqrt{-5}$ and $1-\sqrt{-5}$.  Similarly, $2(1+\sqrt{-5})$ has as divisors $2,1+\sqrt{-5}$ but 2 does not divide $1+\sqrt{-5}$ nor the opposite  so for the common divisors there is not one that is multiple of the others

Comment: Dear Manolis, That's correct.  Regards,

Comment: Is it, though? I only see that _for these two_ common divisors, neither is "the largest". Can't there still be some other common divisor which is "larger" than 2 and $1+\sqrt{-5}$?